# Configuring Pie chart to use minimum space and never hide labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to configure the pie chart to use the minimum space possible.

1. I have set the fixed diameter (to the circle, not to the container) so that i can compare two charts.
2. Did not set the fixed width and height (to the container) as it can hide the labels (Labels are dynamic. Sometimes they can be long. And they are of different length for each chart.)

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/otLv70rj/8/).
Please note that there are two charts one below the other.

Here is my code:

```
$(function ()
{
  draw('container1');
  draw('container2');
  function draw(id)
  {
      $('#' + id).highcharts(
      {
          chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie'
                },
          title:{ text: null },
          legend: { enabled: false },
          credits: { enabled: false },
          tooltip: { pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>' },
          plotOptions: {
                          pie: {
                                  size: 100,
                                  allowPointSelect: true,
                                  cursor: 'pointer',
                                  dataLabels: {
                                      enabled: true,
                                      format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                                      style: {
                                          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                      },
          series: [/* data */]
      });
  }
});
```

Current issues:

1. There is some unused space around the chart (gray colored).
2. Right hand side some part of the label is hidden even though there is space available on the left side.

[image: Pie Chart With Unused Space]

Edit 1: From the [api docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) it seem to use default height `400px` and width `600px`, if not set on the container element. Is there any way to instruct it to use the minimum required width and height?

Comment: You can set a custom `width` and `height`. Also you have a typo in your HTML style: `displau` should be `display`. http://jsfiddle.net/otLv70rj/1/

Comment: @Halcyon Thanks. Corrected `display` (and edited jsfiddle link). I don't want to set width and height as in that case i can't have two pie charts with same diameter. In your jsfiddle 2 and 3 issues are still present (though above and below no space is wasted...

Comment: can you not set the width and height of the div that contains the chart?

Comment: @RahulSharma No. As that may hide (at least part of) the labels. Please note that labels are dynamic and they may have different length than what i can test.

Comment: Do the labels have spaces? You can set the width and height of the container to support labels of a specific length. If the labels do not fit in the screen then you can make them fall in to the next line. This can be achieved by setting width in style attribute of the datalabels config object.

Comment: @RahulSharma Unfortunately no. Worlds are separated by _.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to achieve here.
If you don't want to increase the div size, then where is the label supposed to go, if not cut-off, when it is too long?

Comment: @RahulSharma I want both the Pies (that circular thing) to have fixed diameter. Not a problem if the outer div size increases or decreases. But it should not leave any unused white space and comments should not be hidden.

Comment: If the labels are too long and you want all of it to be displayed, how can there not be unused white space?

Answer (score 1):

Reason for 2: size of the pie chart, you wouldn't see it if you increase the size.

Reason for 3: highcharts does not automatically recenter the chart if you set the size of the chart, and the center of the chart would be center of the div, which leads to cutting off the labels.
If you don't set the size, highcharts would recenter the chart to accomodate all the labels in the plot area.

Try using minSize instead of size.